# 'document.getElementById(...) is null' error when submitting HTML form

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to submit a form and handle the data with JavaScript, but it is not working. I am getting a 'TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null' error when trying to access the data of the form element. The JavaScript IS called, it is just not getting the form data. I am not seeing the data in the URL either.

I saw a few posts where people said that the source code should be below the code, and that did not work. I tried changing the IDs to names, and that did not work. I tried changing my action to different things and that did not work.

```
HTML file: 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>

    <script src="/../wsb/src/stockPurchase/stockPurchase.js"></script>

    <form autocomplete="off" id="stockPurchaseForm" action="/../wsb/src/stockPurchase/stockPage.html" onsubmit="return purchaseStock()">
        <input type="text" id="myStock"     placeholder="Stock"><br>
        <input type="text" id="amt"         placeholder="amt"><br>  
        <input type="submit" value="Go">
    </form>
```

JavaScript, filename=stockPurchase.js:

```
function purchaseStock() {
    document.write("purchase stock called"); //checks to see if js is called

    stock = document.getElementById("myStock").value; 
    amt = document.getElementById("amt").value;

    document.write("The stock is " + stock + " and the amount is " + amt);


}
```

```js
function purchaseStock() {
  document.write("purchase stock called"); //checks to see if js is called

  stock = document.getElementById("myStock").value;
  amt = document.getElementById("amt").value;

  document.write("The stock is " + stock + " and the amount is " + amt);


}
```

```html
<form autocomplete="off" id="stockPurchaseForm" action="/../wsb/src/stockPurchase/stockPage.html" onsubmit="return purchaseStock()">
  <input type="text" id="myStock" placeholder="Stock"><br>
  <input type="text" id="amt" placeholder="amt"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

Expected results: Data is submitted through form. JavaScript on page accesses the data by using document.getElementById(..).value, and I am able to print the data.

Actual results: document.getElementById(..).value is null, and

```
Form submission canceled because the form is not connected
```

Though note, the function IS called, since the initial document.write is called.

Comment: Calling `document.write()` after the page initially loads will wipe out everything on the page. Perhaps you might look into `console.log()`

Answer (score 0):

The `document.write()` operation clears the DOM and calls `document.open()`. If you are trying to write the string `"The stock is " + stock + " and the amount is " + amt` you should select element you want the data appended to and call `.innerText = "The stock is " + stock + " and the amount is " + amt` on it.

You can test this by changing `document.write()` to `console.log()`

```
function purchaseStock() {
    console.log("purchase stock called"); //checks to see if js is called

    stock = document.getElementById("myStock").value; 
    amt = document.getElementById("amt").value;

    console.log("The stock is " + stock + " and the amount is " + amt);
}
```